# Two sides in page view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create an app that has two sides (like a book) using Page View Controller. Can someone give me some tutorials, sample code or links in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `Page View Controller` Use this [LINK](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)
I hope it will work best for you. Please try to google up before asking sample example. There are plenty of stuff available in Internet. The things only required is your Curiosity.

Comment: I've already checked this out. It's a very good tutorial. But, I'm still searching for page view controller that has two sides.

Comment: I've already created an app (magazine like app) using page view controller and it works fine with page curl transition style. The app can navigate through pages within the app. But, I wanted to navigate the app with two sides per page instead of one, to make it a book like look.

Comment: After all the research I've made, I've come up with this - (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;

Comment: @letsgotim i think, i have tried my best to help you, if it is so consider it by accepting answer, it might help full to others also..because i know i did not provide u exact what u need but given u my best